# Prevent Veracrypt (or any other program) from changing the order of boot loaders

Tags: bios, multi-boot, grub, bootloader, veracrypt

Have an installation with dual boot basically as described in the following question: [Veracrypt full disk encryption multi-boot Windows 10 and two Linux Distro on same SSD with some shared folders?](https://superuser.com/questions/1282868/veracrypt-full-disk-encryption-multi-boot-windows-10-and-two-linux-distro-on-sam)

For Windows I am using Veracrypt and for Linux native home folder encryption. Since some updates I am having the following problem: The Veracrypt boot loader is always moved in front of the grub boot loader as soon as I started into Windows. But I want Grub to be the first boot loader.

So everytime I boot and want to start Linux I have to go into the BIOS, move the Ubuntu Boot Loader (grub) in front of the Veracrypt boot loader and restart afterwards. Within Grub I can change between all my currently installed boot loaders also Veracrypt therefore I want this to be my primary boot loader always.

How can I make my system to keep the order of boot loaders as long as this is not explicitly changed in BIOS (some recommend EasyUEFI by Haeslo but this is not a free tool and I do not think that I need commercial software just for this easy task)?

Comment: What updates are you talking about?

Comment: @Ramhound Updated Windows 10 from older builds and Veracrypt from version 1.21 to 1.24.hotfix1. But this should not necessarily be relevant to answer the question.

Comment: It certainly does not matter otherwise I would not have asked for the information

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Within the Veracrypt forums I got some help regarding this issue:

> This is a new change that was added in 1.24-Hotfix1 to solve issues on
>   some machines where the BIOS would remove our entry in boot menu
>   and/or remove VeraCrypt bootloader from disk. Now, before every
>   shutdown or reboot, we ensure that VeraCrypt boot configuration is
>   preserved and that we are set as first
>
> But we have added a registry key that allows disabling this mechanism:
>   using Windows RegEdit, browse to the key
>   `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\VeraCryptSystemFavorites\`, you will find a `REG_DWORD` value named
>   "VeraCryptSystemFavoritesConfig" (create it if it is not there),
>   double click on it, set its value to 1 and click OK. After that,
>   VeraCrypt will not check or fix any change in the boot configuration
>   or bootloader files content before every shutdown or reboot.

**Source:** https://sourceforge.net/p/veracrypt/discussion/general/thread/8b880c2b26/#1060

**Note:** This problem will be fixed within the next release of Veracrypt. Dual-Boot setups are not altered than anymore.

Comment: I'm on a dual-boot setup in VeraCrypt 1.24u6, & this has not been fixed.  It still broke my setup, which I reported on Github 25 days ago (but was ignored) before I finally started reading through their commit logs myself, found the registry key, which is what led me here.  Github report: https://github.com/veracrypt/VeraCrypt/issues/612 .